# fullBaseUrl not correctly used for images when sending mails via console

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

We recently switched our mail implementation to be console-based.

Unfortunately, the following Helper-code within an e-mail view is now broken:

```
$this->Html->image('file.png', array('fullBase' => true)
```

Although we set CakeEmail's domain var to the correct value:

```
$email->domain('www.domain.tld');
```

The helper produces the following

```
http://home/www/domain.tld/htdocs/img/file.png?1382530379
```

**Current behavior:**
The asset timestamping of the file just works like a charme, but the fullBase is unfortunately, I think due to the console call, the UNIX-path of the file.

**Expected behavior:**
The fullBaseUrl should be the domain, which we're setting in the CakeEmail object.

Folks: Is there any other possibility, besides putting the domain on my own to the $this->Html->image() call?

Answer (score 1):

### CakeEmail::domain doesn't do what you want

The domain function is not there for configuring the base url in assets, it's purpose is to [serve as the host name for the message id](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-emails-from-cli). A quick look at [the code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php#L948), and checking where `$this->_domain` is used should confirm that it's only use is related to message headers.

### fullBaseUrl

The option to set is `App.fullBaseUrl` either by [calling Router::fullBaseUrl](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Routing/Router.php#L911):

```
// inside email-sending command, before sending an email
Router::fullBaseUrl('http://example.com');
```

Or by configuring it directly [in core.php](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/core.php#L111):

```
// anywhere before an email is sent
Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', 'http://example.com');
```

Comment: I tested this by setting Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', 'https://domain.tld'); 

But I received the following output in the mail: 
https://domain.tld/home/www/domain.tld/htdocs/img/file.png?1382530379

Comment: I assume you mean you're missing `http://` - which isn't surprising since it's not in the string you've specified

Comment: sorry, stackoverflow is doing some auto-magic here.

i define `('APP.fullBaseUrl', 'https://domain.tld')` and receive an image href of `https://domain.tld/home/www/domain.tld/htdocs/…`

Comment: I see (sort of, please use `backticks to format code` =)), you're referring to the path. That's not related to changing the base url, you'll need to investigate (e.g. debug `$this->request->webroot` in your email template and then determine why it is not `/`, or simply debug how you're obtaining that string when requesting the image url).